# Virtuemart and Joomla: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'iZoom'

Tags: jquery, joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2.0.12.

Now, I installed a virtuemart template, on top of my normal Joomla template.

Now, the following error occurs:

When opening a product details page in Virtuemart, the thumbnails of the product are not working, as well as the zoom. Also, the button to add a product to the cart, is not working.

This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'iZoom'

This is the code that is in the .js file:

```
// Lets Load The Lens Effect ;-)
bigImage.iZoom({
    borderColor: '#e1e0e0', // set the loupe border color
    borderWidth: '3px', // set the loupe border width
         diameter: '170'
});
```

How would I be able to solve this problem?
I installed absolutely no other components or Modules in Joomla.

Thank you in advance.

JorritK

Answer (score 0):

The solution for you could be javascript conflict.

Few days ago I have had similar problem with Joomla! 2.5 template (jat3 template - JA Portfolio for be more specific) and slider module written by myself. 
Firstly I thought the problem is caused by my module but it was not.

My error was similar to your:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElements'
```

As You can see errors are almost the same, only the method are different but I think it is irrelevant in this case. This error occurs when javascrips confict appers because program do not know which library it should use or it is overwritten (the reference for $ sign) by joomla - but it depends.

I must admit I have never used Virtuemart and do not know what kind of javascript is included into template use but I'm certain that the solution for You is to focus to put line with:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

..whenever jQuery library has been included.

I solved my problem with these few lines into my main `.php` file in my module:

```
if($loadJquery) $document->addScript(ModSlideshowHelper::getJqueryFile($jqueryFile));
if($jqueryNoConflict) $document->addScript(ModSlideshowHelper::getJqueryNoConflictFile());
```

As you noticed first line add jQuery script, second line include static function. The file that load second function contains only single line `jQuery.noConflict();`

```
public static function getJqueryNoConflictFile()
{
    return 'modules'.DS.'mod_slideshow'.DS.'js'.DS.'jquery-no-conflict.js';
}
```

Hope this example help